# js: Show text saved in localStorage on same page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm a total beginner in javascript and spend too much time trying to get this working.
What I want to do:

1.html generates sentences from different arrays. So the user can push the button "generate" and the arrays will combine randomly, as long as there is a sentence he/she likes. I need this generated sentence on  2.html. I used `localStorage` to store the generated sentence. The thing I want to get working is, that the generated sentence on 1.html is also shown on 1.html after the User pushes the "generate" button. Never got it working properly.

I replaced the words of the sentences with letters for now.

Here the code of 1.html

```js
let green, display, button, clock, end;
    green = ["a", "d", "d", "v"];
    display = ["f", "g", "v", "h"];
    button = ["h", "r", "h", "h"];
    clock = ["h", "t", "c", "r"];
    end = ["g", "t", "x", "r"];
    
    
    
    function sentence() {
      let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        
      let content = clock[rand1] + " " + display[rand1] + " " + button[rand1] + " " + green[rand1] + " " + end[rand1];
    
      return content;
    }
    
    // Check browser support
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("sentence", sentence());
    }
```

```html
<h1>Generator</h1>
    <button onclick="sentence()">generate</button>
```

This is 2.html

```html
<div id="result"></div>
     
    <script>
        // Check browser support
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sentence");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Browser does not support Web Storage.";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working? Do you see the entry called `sentence` in the browser's dev tools? Do you see an error message in the console? Simplify your code for testing purposes and call `localStorage.setItem("sentence", "some text")` instead of `localStorage.setItem("sentence", sentence())`. Until you find the buggy piece

Comment: What doesn't work: if i push the "generate" Button it safes the sentence in localStorage, but if push it again, it won't overwrite the old one. In 2.html it still show's the first sentence generated.
and the second thing i want to get working is, that the sentence in 1.html is not only safed to localStorage, but also shown in 1.html below the button.
There are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `sentence()` does not by itself save to localStorage. It only generates a new sentence each time it's called. You can change as follows:

```js
function sentence() {
  let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    
  let content = clock[rand1] + " " + display[rand1] + " " + button[rand1] + " " + green[rand1] + " " + end[rand1];

    // Check browser support
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("sentence", content);
    }

    const message = document.querySelector('.message');
    message.innerText = content;
}
```

And in 1.html add this:

```html
<div class="message"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think i even unterstood why i didn't get it working.